# Account and customer balances (virtual columns)

Tags: oracle, function, virtual

I have customers that can have one or more accounts. I'm calling 2 functions
(get_customer_balance and get_account_balance) to calculate balances.

As you can see from my test CASE below I'm calling the functions twice in each query. I was wondering would these scenarios be candidates for virtual fields? If so, how can this be implemented?

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
CUSTOMER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,IS_ACTIVE) AS  SELECT 'L382059', 'Leo', 'Langford','Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'P382319', 'Tom', 'Micelli','Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'E379466', 'Bonnie', 'Winterbottom','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'X060162', 'Lisa','Saladino','Y'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Y331964', 'Sandy', 'Herring','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Z888555', 'Barbara', 'Broadwater','Y' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE vendors AS
    SELECT level AS vendor_id,
       'Vendor ' || level AS vendor_name
    FROM   dual
    CONNECT BY level <= 3;

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS (
ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
CUSTOMER_ID, VENDOR_ID,
IS_ACTIVE) AS 
SELECT 'Z17ARWYYZRCU2Q2', 'P382319', 1, 'Y' FROM DUAL 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '0T81Z07CS6LXQ7Z', 'P382319', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'YWYXC3Q5N9XZ7S', 'L382059', 1, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '612ZKAQ66VA3W3', 'Y331964', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL    UNION ALL 
SELECT 'BCHD9TW78W67S1D', 'Z888555', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT '0HLS87LDR1TE8WB', 
'X060162', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Z69AG7DKS37UYU',
'X060162', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B17ARWYYZRCU2Q2', 
'X060162', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'THVQD6M9LR7AVK', 'E379466', 1, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT '0Z76WT5NTLRZPTW',
'E379466', 1, 'Y' FROM DUAL;

create table transactions (
     transaction_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    account_number VARCHAR2(15),
    transaction_type varchar2(1) DEFAULT 'C',
    transaction_amount NUMBER(10,2),
     transaction_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE 
);

insert  into transactions(
account_number, transaction_type, transaction_amount, transaction_date)
SELECT 'Z17ARWYYZRCU2Q2', 'D', (LEVEL * 1250.50), date '2023-05-14' + level * interval '5 15:13' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 7
union all
SELECT 'Z17ARWYYZRCU2Q2', 'C', (LEVEL * 1175.75), date '2023-07-04' + level * interval '1 21:23' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 5
union all
SELECT '0T81Z07CS6LXQ7Z', 'D', (LEVEL * 1250.50), date '2023-02-14' + level * interval '3 15:13' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 17
union all
SELECT '0T81Z07CS6LXQ7Z', 'C', (LEVEL * 75.75), date '2023-02-04' + level * interval '2 21:23' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 11
union all
select '612ZKAQ66VA3W3', 'D', 555.25 * LEVEL, (DATE '2023-07-13' + 13/24) + (level * 2)  from dual 
    connect by level <= 25 
UNION ALL 
select '612ZKAQ66VA3W3', 'C', 555.25 * LEVEL, (DATE '2023-07-23' + 13/24) + (level * 2)  from dual 
    connect by level <= 20 
UNION ALL 
SELECT '0HLS87LDR1TE8WB', 'D', (LEVEL * 1250.50), date '2023-05-04' + level * interval '1 15:13' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 7
union all
SELECT '0HLS87LDR1TE8WB', 'C', (LEVEL * 1175.75), date '2023-05-04' + level * interval '1 15:13' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 5
union all
SELECT 'Z69AG7DKS37UYU', 'D', ((LEVEL * 5) * 1750), date '2023-06-01' + level * interval '1 18:43:35' day to second from dual
          connect by level <= 15
union all
SELECT 'Z69AG7DKS37UYU', 'C', ((LEVEL * 5) * 1750), date '2023-06-11' + level * interval '1 15:23:49' day to second from dual
          connect by level <= 13;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION   get_customer_balance
(  i_customer_id   IN   customers.customer_id%TYPE
)
RETURN  transactions.transaction_amount%TYPE
IS
  v_balance   transactions.transaction_amount%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM (
                 CASE  t.transaction_type
             WHEN  'C'
             THEN  -t.transaction_amount
             ELSE  t.transaction_amount
         END 
             )
  INTO   v_balance
  FROM   customer_accounts  ca
  JOIN   transactions       t  ON  t.account_number  = ca.account_number
  WHERE  ca.customer_id  = i_customer_id  -- one customer
  OR     ca.customer_id  IS NULL;         -- all customers

  RETURN v_balance;
END  get_customer_balance;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_account_balance(
  i_account_number IN TRANSACTIONS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER%TYPE
) RETURN TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT%TYPE
IS
  v_balance TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(
           CASE transaction_type WHEN 'C' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END 
           * transaction_amount
         )
  INTO   v_balance
  FROM   transactions
  WHERE  account_number = i_account_number -- one account
  OR     i_account_number IS NULL;         -- all accounts
  RETURN v_balance;
END;
/

SELECT 
    CA.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 
     C.CUSTOMER_ID, 
     C.FIRST_NAME, 
     C.LAST_NAME, 
   get_account_balance(ca.account_number) AS balance 
  FROM CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS CA
INNER JOIN customers c ON ca.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE get_account_balance(ca.account_number)  > 200000; 

ACCOUNT_NUMBER  CUSTOMER_ID 
 FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME  BALANCE
Z69AG7DKS37UYU  X060162  Lisa  Saladino 253750

SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID,
       C.FIRST_NAME,
       C.LAST_NAME, 
       get_customer_balance(C.CUSTOMER_ID) AS balance
FROM   customers c
WHERE get_customer_balance(C.CUSTOMER_ID) > 200000;


CUSTOMER_ID  FIRST_NAME 
 LAST_NAME. BALANCE
P382319  Tom  Micelli 
 203704.75
X060162  Lisa  Saladino 
 271127.75
```

Answer (score 2):

Virtual columns aren't precomputed so you wouldn't save on resource cost by calling the functions from VCs. The exception is if you indexed them, but then you have to prevent them from going stale; you don't want to be continually rebuilding your index to keep them accurate.

I suggest just using normal SQL instead of functions. The use of functions will require separate lookup and sorts for every single customer, which can bog down if you are running this against a very large customer base. Try this, the only difference between the two being an additional `GROUP BY` column:

```
-- customer balance
SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID,
       C.FIRST_NAME,
       C.LAST_NAME, 
       SUM(CASE transaction_type WHEN 'C' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * transaction_amount) customer_balance
 FROM  customers c
       JOIN customer_accounts  ca ON ca.customer_id = c.customer_id
       JOIN transactions t  ON  t.account_number  = ca.account_number
 GROUP BY C.CUSTOMER_ID,
          C.FIRST_NAME,
          C.LAST_NAME
HAVING SUM(CASE transaction_type WHEN 'C' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * transaction_amount) > 200000;  

-- account balance
SELECT ca.account_number,
       C.CUSTOMER_ID,
       C.FIRST_NAME,
       C.LAST_NAME, 
       SUM(CASE transaction_type WHEN 'C' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * transaction_amount) account_balance
 FROM  customers c
       JOIN customer_accounts  ca ON ca.customer_id = c.customer_id
       JOIN transactions t  ON  t.account_number  = ca.account_number
 GROUP BY ca.account_number,
          C.CUSTOMER_ID,
          C.FIRST_NAME,
          C.LAST_NAME
HAVING SUM(CASE transaction_type WHEN 'C' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * transaction_amount) > 200000;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I decided with the function in the first place as it will be called in several different places from the application. I believed that maintaining the code in one place out weighted having it in several places. I'll do more research

Comment: @Pugzly - Does your function perform acceptably? If so, there's no issue. If not, then either tune the SQL to be as fast as possible, or take my advice and don't use a function. In the database world we rarely have the luxury of having a piece of SQL in one place only as a matter of principle. Performance concerns usually trump that.

Comment: @Pugzly Oh, and if you do want to tune your functions, I'd start by taking out or fixing that `OR     ca.customer_id  IS NULL` clause.